# php7 - prevent errors being broadcast

Tags: php, centos-7, systemd, syslog

On Centos7 With PHP 7 configured to send errors to syslog, parse errors get broadcast to wall e.g. logged in users see messages like this:

```
Broadcast message from systemd-journald@xxxxxxxxxx (Fri 2017-03-03 22:29:05 UTC):

httpd[3465]: PHP Parse error:  Invalid numeric literal in /web/test.php on line 20
```

I would like to trap these messages and prevent them going to wall. I've tried this Rsyslog config:

```
user.*                                                /var/log/php.log
& stop
```

however it did not prevent the broadcast messages. Editing `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` to include `ForwardToWall=no` prevents the broadcast message... The problem is it prevents **all** emergency messages being displayed which is not desirable.

How can I prevent PHP parse errors being broadcast, but allow other critical system messages to be logged to console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that putting `ForwardToWall=no` & `ForwardToSyslog=yes` into `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` resolves the issue.

Emerg message from PHP get caught with this custom Rsyslog config:

```
user.*                                                /var/log/php.log
& stop
```

And other emerg messages get caught later on with:

```
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
```

Which has sends the messages to all logged in users.